# Convert SQL to LINQ with JOIN, GROUP BY, SUM, multiply values two List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT
    (SUM(L.total_linea) * I.porcentaje / 100) AS iva
FROM 
    linea_ventas L 
JOIN 
    iva I ON L.id_iva = I.id_iva
GROUP BY 
    L.id_iva
```

I tried to write the query with the LINQPad 5 program directly against my database before adding it in my code but I am blocked here:

```
 from l in linea_ventas
    join i in ivas on l.id_iva equals i.id_iva
    group l by new { l.id_iva } into g
    select new
    {
       iva = g.Sum(l => l.total_linea)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL query is not correct, as you should bring what you have in SELECT clause in GROUP BY clause (unless you use it in an aggregation function), so here you should use `I.porcentaje` in GROUP BY, although I do not think grouping by something like percentage is what you want.

I guess you want to sum all the `total_linea` considering `porcentaje`, so, for example, you can write your query as this:

You have joined tables correctly, after joining, because you only need `id_iva` and `total_linea` and `porcentaje`, gather only these values in an anonymous type,
then group them by `id_iva` (as you did yourself), then choose values in your groupings and do your calculations:

```
var result = from l in linea_ventas
    join i in ivas on l.id_iva equals i.id_iva
    select new {
                 l.id_iva,
                 value = l.total_linea * i.porcentaje / 100
               } into selected
    group selected by selected.id_iva into groups
    select groups.Sum(v => v.value);
```

Comment: I need to order descending by percentage. I have placed this code `orderby g.OrderByDescending(o => o.Porcentaje)` under group by. This is correct?